# Error at SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm just a newbie in android and trying to understand database so pls be nice.

My problem that the log is pointing is on the line where I'm calling the   getWritableDatabase()

Error
[image]

```
private DatabaseHandler ourDb;
private static Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase sdb;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
     ourDb = new DatabaseHandler(ourContext);
     sdb =ourDb.getWritableDatabase();
```

and the codes in DatabaseHandler class is the one I followed in this link [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

So can anybody pls tell me how to solve the error thanks!

Comment: Please post the logcat with exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is in your context. It is null

```
ourDb = new DatabaseHandler(ourContext);
```

initialize your context with

```
ourContext=  MainActivity.this;
```

or pass "getApplicationContext()", "this" in your initialization

```
ourDb = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: btw, Vaibhav i have one more question. In what tab can i find the /data/data/package.... folder?

Comment: go to DDMS then select your device in right side in devices window then in file explorer you can find your app folder

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` you passed to `DatabaseHandler` is `null`.

Since you seem to be in an `Activity`, use `this` instead of uninitialized `ourContext`.

Comment: OK that sucked up my time tnx! Ill accepts this as my answer :)